# Should Airflow and Jupyter be decoupled to 2 dockers

Tags: python, docker, airflow

The airflow is to schedule python and jupyter jobs.
There are environment settings, directories and installed python and linux packages used by the python code.
Should airflow be installed in a separate docker or in the same docker?
If it is in a separate docker, how can the env, directories, installed packages be shared to the airflow?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally yes, that way you can scale/restart Airflow and Jupyter independently of each other, without having to take down everything.

For environment variables and packages, you will need to set these on both containers. To avoid code duplication, you might want to look at e.g. a `.env` file so that you don't have to define the same variables twice. See e.g. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option

Files can be shared on a shared volume. How to set this up depends on your container management system. E.g. [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Do I need to restart the Airflow whenever I installed a new python package?

Comment: Anything that relies on your new Python package will need a restart, so it's safe to always restart yes.